# nodeValue remains null after assigning number

Tags: javascript, dom

I use the following code to create a new DOM element and assign a value.

```
var xCoordElem = document.createElement("xCoord");
xCoordElem.nodeValue=Canvas.paper.someCircle.attr('cx');
```

where `Canvas.paper.someCircle` is made using

```
Canvas.paper = Raphael(xOffset,yOffset,width,height);
Canvas.someCircle = Canvas.paper.circle(x, y, radius);
```

I then call

```
alert("Canvas.paper.someCircle .attr('cx')=" + Canvas.paper.someCircle .attr('cx');
alert("xCoordElem.nodeValue=" + xCoordElem.nodeValue);
```

The first alert box gives "Canvas.paper.someCircle .attr('cx')=562" while the second alert box gives "xCoordElem.nodeValue=null".  I am testing this on FireFox, using FireBug and FireBug also says that `xCoordElem.nodeValue=null`.

I am hoping to make `xCoordElem.nodeValue` the value of `Canvas.paper.someCircle .attr('cx')` (in this case 562) instead of `null`.

Comment: Put first alert box just before second line of your above code. see what is alert box is showing

Comment: It is better to use `console.log(...)` rather than `alert(...)`.

Comment: Sushil.  I am not sure what to put.  The xCoordElem looks fine in FireBug.  It is just the nodeValue field that is problematic.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Vivin.  I used console.log(...) and got the same results as with alert(...).  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Try taking the single quotes off cx when you assign it to nodevalue

Comment: Replacing the single quotes with double quotes had not effect.  I don't think JavaScript distinguishes between the two.  Plus Canvas.paper.someCircle.attr('cx') has the right value.  The problem seem to be getting that value into xCoordElem.nodeValue.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .prop() method instead of attr. As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method. - from the Jquery API documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I tried xCoordElem.nodeValue=Canvas.paper.someCircle.prop('cx'); and the JS console returned "Canvas.paper.someCircle.prop is not a function".  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: It looks like I can get around the problem by using xCoordElem.textContent=Canvas.paper.someCircle.attr('cx');.  That way the number I am wanting is saved, in text form, in the element.  Thanks, Peter.